# How to set a custom consumer task executor for Spring Kafka, when using auto-configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In lines [226-230](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/v2.1.0.RELEASE/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java#L226-L230) of `org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer`, Spring Kafka assigns a default `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` as the listener container's consumer task executor:

```java
    if (containerProperties.getConsumerTaskExecutor() == null) {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor consumerExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor(
                (getBeanName() == null ? "" : getBeanName()) + "-C-");
        containerProperties.setConsumerTaskExecutor(consumerExecutor);
    }
```

In the docs, it is pointed out that it is [possible](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_container_thread_naming) to use a custom executor instead of `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`:

> If you don’t provide a consumer executor, a `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` is used; this executor creates threads with names `<beanName>-C-1` (consumer thread). For the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`, the `<beanName>` part of the thread name becomes `<beanName>-m`, where `m` represents the consumer instance. `n` increments each time the container is started. So, with a bean name of container, threads in this container will be named `container-0-C-1`, `container-1-C-1` etc., after the container is started the first time; `container-0-C-2`, `container-1-C-2` etc., after a stop/start.

However I can't find a way to customize the executor when Spring Boot's auto-configuration is enabled for Kafka (i.e. `KafkaAutoConfiguration`).

In short, what is the correct way to set (`ContainerProperties#consumerTaskExecutor`)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can't do that via configuration properties, because it's not so simple property, but you can override the bean:

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer kafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer();
    configurer.setKafkaProperties(this.properties);
    return configurer;
}
```

with  your custom implementaiton. And in its `configure()` method call an appropriate `listenerContainerFactory.getContainerProperties().setConsumerTaskExecutor()`.

Comment: Hi Artem. IMHO, Spring Kafka should first check to see if a custom executor bean (or executor factory bean) is provided by the user and only use `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` if such a bean was not defined (e.g. a bean of type `Executor` named `kafkaConsumerTaskExecutor`). In the meantime I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Well, feel free to raise such an issue against Spring Boot. That is exactly the place where we auto-configure Spring Kafka by convention. The Spring Kafka is not the place for such a convention.

Comment: When I do that (sample code [here](https://gist.github.com/behrangsa/07090b1bdc1c0455a69e5fda8b69a524)), some of the `application.yml` properties are not picked up anymore. For example `spring.kafka.cnsumer.auto-offset-reset`.

Comment: You have to inject `KafkaProperties` into the `configurer.setKafkaProperties(this.properties);`

Comment: I do @ [L10-13](https://gist.github.com/behrangsa/07090b1bdc1c0455a69e5fda8b69a524#file-main-java-L10). The `setKafkaProperties` is package-private so I instead inject it using customer injection.

Comment: Oh, really? I would suggest to raise an issue for Spring Boot to make them `public`. I don't see reason why would one restrict such an access.

Comment: IMHO, there should have been a `KafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` interface with `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer` being one of its implementations. I will raise a ticket.

Comment: Issue raised, feel free to upvote: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12003

Comment: This can't be public as the configurer would effectively be mutable and we don't want that.